# Sequelize How to save without changing updatedAt?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it anyhow possible to NOT update the updatedAt value on sequelize model.save()?

I'm incrementing counters of an object and do not update the model at its root, thus I'd like the updatedAt value to stay as it is. Is this anyhow possible with sequelize?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to perform

```
instance.save ({ silent: true })
```

Adding this prevents changing the `updatedAt` value. [Read `save` options](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/instance/#saveoptions-promisethiserrorsvalidationerror)